# Can I customize the way that Rails filters a parameter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

I want to filter certain user information so that sensitive info is not captured in the logs. However, in one case, I want to log the format instead of the default, `"[FILTERED]"`.

For example, I'd like to make this transformation:

```
# user input    value to log
"e6132 DG71" => "a9999 AA99"
```

This would help us troubleshoot users' issues.

Can I use a custom filter (maybe a proc?) for Rails' `filter_parameters` method?

Answer (score 4):

### Append a lambda filter

You can append a lambda filter to `Rails.application.config.filter_parameters`. Only parameters that aren't caught by the typical filtering will go on to the custom filtering.

```
# Typical filters - will show as [FILTERED]
Rails.application.config.filter_parameters += [
  :password
]

# Custom filter - this only sees what the previous list didn't catch
Rails.application.config.filter_parameters << lambda do |param_name, value|
  if %w[foo_param bar_param].include?(param_name) && value.respond_to?(:gsub!)
    # Alter the string in place because we don't have access to 
    # the hash to update the key's value
    value.gsub!(/[a-z]/, "a")
    value.gsub!(/[A-Z]/, "A")
    value.gsub!(/[0-9]/, "9")
    # Stick this at the beginning to make it easy to see in logs
    value.gsub!(/\A/, "[FORMAT FILTERED]")
  end
end
```

Note that the default filters match as regexes; `:password` is treated as `/password/`. You could do likewise for the custom filter:

```
if [/foo/, /bar/].detect {|r| r.match(param_name) }
  # ...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Reading the [ActionDispatch::Http::FilterParameters docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/FilterParameters.html) for Rails 4.2, there is an option to pass a block to `parameter_filter` to customize the filter behaviour. I assume you can do something like this:

```
 env["action_dispatch.parameter_filter"] = lambda do |k,v|
   your_transformation(v) if k =~ /secret/i
 end
```

where `your_transformation` knows how to deal with the user input labeled `secret` to transform it into `a9999 AA99`. I also guess you'll have to handle your already present `filtered_attributes` to keep the `[FILTERED]` behavior.